# How to error handle command line arguments?

Tags: c++, function, error-handling, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to error handle command line arguments with a function like this:

```
int check(char *r){
    int arg, valid = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<sizeof(*r); i++){
        if(!isdigit(r[i]))
            valid = 0;
        else if (atoi(r)<1)
            valid = 0;
        else
            valid = 1;
    }
    if (valid == 1)
        arg = atoi(r);
    while(valid == 0){
        cout<<"Input was wrong! Please input a positive integer greater than 0: ";
        cin>>arg;
        if (arg<1 || cin.fail()){
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
            valid = 0;
        }
        else
            valid = 1;
    }
    return arg;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
  int player;
  int row;
  int col;

  for (int i = 1; i<7; i+=2){
    if(argv[i][0] == '-' && argv[i][1] == 'p'){
        player = check( argv[i+1] );
    }
    else if (argv[i][0] == '-' && argv[i][1] == 'r'){
        row = check( argv[i+1] );
    }
    else if (argv[i][0] == '-' && argv[i][1] == 'c'){
        col = check( argv[i+1] );
    }
    else
        cout<<"Enter -p <number of players> -r <number of rows> -c <number of columns> "<<endl;
  }
}
```

But it won't compile, saying that there was no matching function call to check. An example of what the user should input is "./a.out -p 2 -r 6 -c 7". What is the best way to check if the user is only inputting positive integers in the command line?

The compiler outputs the following message when compiling.

```
    main.cpp:41:15: error: no matching function for call to
      'check'
            player = check( argv[i+1] );
                     ^~~~~
main.cpp:8:5: note: candidate function not viable: 1st
      argument ('const char *') would lose const qualifier
int check(char *r){
    ^
main.cpp:44:12: error: no matching function for call to
      'check'
            row = check( argv[i+1] );
                  ^~~~~
main.cpp:8:5: note: candidate function not viable: 1st
      argument ('const char *') would lose const qualifier
int check(char *r){
    ^
main.cpp:47:12: error: no matching function for call to
      'check'
            col = check( argv[i+1] );
                  ^~~~~
main.cpp:8:5: note: candidate function not viable: 1st
      argument ('const char *') would lose const qualifier
int check(char *r){
```

Comment: `sizeof(*r)` is wrong. Note that in `c++` sizeof() is a compile time constant.

Comment: Apart from what @drescherjm said, you need `int check(const char *r){...` (note the `const`)

Comment: Read the note for the error message. (Notes go with whatever preceded them.) There is no matching function because the first argument is `const char *`, but the declared function expects `char *`, and throwing away `const` is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char const*` to `char*` is not a valid conversion, you need to remove const from `char const *argv[]`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

or add const to `char *r`

```
int check(const char *r)
```

---

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

with

```
int check(const char *r)
```

is also valid.

Also `sizeof(*r)` is the size of a single char, not the size of the char array you pass as an argument.